# Lost records when using Rpy2 execute r-script and write results to a csv file

Tags: python, django, rpy2

I have been having problem of missing records in the output file when using Rpy2 execute r-script and the script has function of writing analysis results to a csv file. Please see below for the source code.

For example, I have 785 records in my source file (f2), and after analyzing there should be 785 file in output file (processed). However, I get fewer records in output file. There is no such problem when I run the r-script directly in R. Does anybody know what cold be wrong? Thanks.

```
def make_standardization(filename,outdata):
traindata = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "default_predict_train.csv") 
testdata = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename) 


robjects.r.assign("f1",traindata)
robjects.r.assign("f2",testdata)
robjects.r.assign("processed", outdata)

robjects.r("""
    train.dta=read.csv(f1,header=T)
    test.dta=read.csv(f2,header=T)

    train.h=train.dta[,c(1:2)]
    train.x=train.dta[,-c(1:2)]
    train.colnames=sub("PFGE.XbaI.","",colnames(train.x))
    train.colnames=as.numeric(train.colnames)

    test.h=test.dta[,c(1:2)]
    test.x=test.dta[,-c(1:2)]
    test.x=t(t(test.x))
    temp=matrix(as.numeric(test.x),nrow=nrow(test.x),ncol=ncol(test.x))
    colnames(temp)=colnames(test.x)
    test.x=temp
    test.x[is.na(test.x)]=0.5
    test.colnames=sub("PFGE.XbaI.","",colnames(test.x))
    test.colnames=as.numeric(test.colnames)


    temp=matrix(0,nrow=nrow(test.x),ncol=ncol(train.x))
    colnames(temp)=colnames(train.x)
    rownames(temp)=rownames(test.x)

    for(i in 1:ncol(train.x)){

        if(i == 1) {
            index=which( test.colnames > (train.colnames[i]+train.colnames[i+1])/2    )
            if(length(index)==1){
                temp[,i]=test.x[,index]
            }else{
                temp[,i]=1*(rowSums(test.x[,index])>0)
            }
        }

        if(i == ncol(train.x)) {
            index=which( test.colnames <= (train.colnames[i]+train.colnames[i-1])/2    )
            if(length(index)==1){
                temp[,i]=test.x[,index]
            }else{
                temp[,i]=1*(rowSums(test.x[,index])>0)
            }
        }        

        if(i >1 && i< ncol(train.x)){
            index=which( test.colnames > (train.colnames[i]+train.colnames[i+1])/2  & test.colnames <= (train.colnames[i]+train.colnames[i-1])/2    )
            if(length(index)==1){
                temp[,i]=test.x[,index]
            }else{
                temp[,i]=1*(rowSums(test.x[,index])>0)
            }            
        }            

    }

    test.x=cbind(test.h,temp)

    write.csv(test.x,processed)

""")
```

Comment: I can't imagine that this has something to do with rpy2 -- have you checked to make sure that you're actually using the exact same files when you run the script from python as you are from R?

Comment: You should provide self-contained example code, as much as is possible. Making some up might help you figure out your problem. Also, it'd be helpful if you fixed the indent formatting on your post.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. It turns out not the problem of this code as suspected by Noah. I added flush() to my other part of the code and the problem solved. Thanks.